# Mock DataContext from Linq to SQL with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, moq

I am writing a unit test to Mock a  System.Data.Linq.Table in a data context. My code is as follows (Please find the data context, the entity and the unit test) below. The code does not compile saying it cannot resolve the method. How can I alter this code to be a well formed test?

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name = "MyDB")]
public partial class Table1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
    partial void OnCreated();

    public Table1DataContext() :
        base(global::Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Table1Definition> Table1Definitions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Table1Definition>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.Table1Definition")]
public partial class Table1Definition : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ID;
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_ID", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ID != value))
            {
                this.OnIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ID");
                this.OnIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    partial void OnIDChanging(int value);
    partial void OnIDChanged();
    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    private Mock<Table1DataContext> dataContextMock;

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShoulReturnValidDefinition()
    {
        this.dataContextMock = new Mock<Table1DataContext>();
        this.dataContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Table1Definitions).Returns(GetFakeEntityDefinition());

    }

    private static IList<Table1Definition> GetFakeEntityDefinition()
    {
        return new List<Table1Definition> { new Table1Definition { ID = 1 } };
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a better example of the test you are trying to run?

Comment: The test is not really related here but in my Test I need to Mock the result of the Table1Definitions, Just so i can unit test another piece of work.

Comment: The primary issue I see you are going to run into is that you are attempting to mock a non-virtual member with Moq. This will throw an exception when you run your tests. You need to abstract your code in some way be it an abstract class with virtual methods or an interface. Another option is using another mocking framework that allows you to mock non-virtual members. I would just recommend making it an interface though as that will lead to better code anyway.

Comment: Even i had an abstraction I would need to replace the "System.Data.Linq.Table<Table1Definition> Table1Definitions" with a value and that's what i am struggling with.